# EF: Duplicate Object with all child including sub sub children (Deep Copy)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table with properties like:

`Id   Name   ParentId`

`ParentId` is a foreign key to primary column `Id`. Now lets say I have a few rows like: (Only showing `ParentId` from rows)

```
    NULL
   /    \
  1      2
        / \
       3   4
```

Now, lets say we want to copy row object whose `ParentId` is NULL with it's all sub objects.

```
  var row = db.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == 1);
  var new_row = new Table1();
  var subrows = row.Table1.ToArray();
        foreach(var row in subrows)
        {
            db.Entry(row).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
        }
        new_row.Table1 = subrows;
db.Table.Add(new_row);
db.saveChanges();
```

Result: New inserted structure like:

```
    NULL
   /    \
  1      2
```

I am assuming that only one sublevel is being copied. How to copy/insert all sublevels?

**EDIT:** Since detach was helping create a copy till one level, this is what I tried:

```
private void RecursiveDetach(Table1 parent)
        {
            var subrows = parent.Table1.ToArray();
            foreach (var row in subrows)
            {
                if(row.Table1.Count() > 0)
                {
                    RecursiveDetach(row);
                }
                db.Entry(row).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
            }
        }
```

However, now I am getting an error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Are you working with a self reference relationship or there are involve two different entities?

Comment: I didn't get want you are asking but here more context `Entities db = new Entities();` and here is how the foreign key is defined.  `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_Table] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table] ([Id])`

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this before. I've done it purely in code, recursively copying objects and sanitizing unique IDs where needed, but the cleanest approach I've ever built is serializing the object to XML, then de-serializing into a new object. The approach is less efficient, but fantastically flexible and easy to implement.

```
//Save object to XML file. Returns filename.
public string SaveObjectAsXML(int id)
{
    //however you get your EF context and disable proxy creation
    var db = GetContext(); 
    bool currentProxySetting = db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    //get the data
    var item = db.GetItem(id); //retrieval be unique to your setup, but I have
                               //a more generic solution if you need it. Make
                               //sure you have all the sub items included
                               //in your object or they won't be saved.
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = currentProxySetting;

    //if no item is found, do whatever needs to be done
    if (item == null)
    {                
        return string.Empty;
    }            

    //I actually write my data to a file so I can save states if needed, but you could
    //modify the method to just spit out the XML instead
    Directory.CreateDirectory(DATA_PATH); //make sure path exists to prevent write errors
    string path = $"{DATA_PATH}{id}{DATA_EXT}";
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        bf.Serialize(fs, repair);
    }

    return path;
}

//Load object from XML file. Returns ID.
public int LoadXMLData(string path)
{   
    //make sure the file exists
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        throw new Exception("File not found.");
    }

    //load data from file
    try 
    { 
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
        {
            var item = (YourItemType)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(fs);
            db.YourItemTypes.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return item.Id;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //Exceptions here are common when copying between databases where differences in config entries result in mis-matches
        throw;
    }
}
```

The use is simple.

```
//save object
var savedObjectFilename = SaveObjectAsXML(myObjID);

//loading the item will create a copy
var newID = LoadXMLData(savedObjectFilename);
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a second, totally different answer: recursively detach your whole object instead of just the parent object. The following is written as an extension method to your context object:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively detaches item and sub-items from EF. Assumes that all sub-objects are properties (not fields).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to detach</param>
    /// <param name="recursionDepth">Number of levels to go before stopping. object.Property is 1, object.Property.SubProperty is 2, and so on.</param>
    public static void DetachAll(this DbContext db, object item, int recursionDepth = 3)
    {
        //Exit if no remaining recursion depth
        if (recursionDepth <= 0) return;

        //detach this object
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;

        //get reflection data for all the properties we mean to detach
        Type t = item.GetType();
        var properties = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                          .Where(p => p.GetSetMethod()?.IsPublic == true)  //get only properties we can set                              
                          .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsClass)              //only classes can be EF objects
                          .Where(p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string))    //oh, strings. What a pain.
                          .Where(p => p.GetValue(item) != null);           //only get set properties

        //if we're recursing, we'll check here to make sure we should keep going
        if (properties.Count() == 0) return;

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            //handle generics
            if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                //assume its Enumerable. More logic can be built here if that's not true.
                IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)p.GetValue(item);
                foreach (var obj in collection)
                {
                    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Detached;
                    DetachAll(db, obj, recursionDepth - 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var obj = p.GetValue(item);
                db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Detached;
                DetachAll(db, obj, recursionDepth - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

The biggest thing to look out for will be config-type properties--object that represent data not directly related to the object. These might create conflicts, so better to make sure your object doesn't include them.

**Note:**

This approach requires that all sub-objects you wish to copy be populated in advance, avoiding lazy loading.  To ensure this, I use the following extension for my EF queries:

```
//Given a custom context object such that CustomContext inherits from DbContext AND contains an arbitrary number of DbSet collections
//which represent the data in the database (i.e. DbSet<MyObject>), this method fetches a queryable collection of object type T which
//will preload sub-objects specified by the array of expressions (includeExpressions) in the form o => o.SubObject.
public static IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>(this CustomContext context, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions) where T : class
{
    //look through the context for a dbset of the specified type
    var property = typeof(CustomContext).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                                                                    p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault();

    //if the property wasn't found, we don't have the queryable object. Throw exception
    if (property == null) throw new Exception("No queryable context object found for Type " + typeof(T).Name);

    //create a result of that type, then assign it to the dataset
    IQueryable<T> source = (IQueryable<T>)property.GetValue(context);

    //return 
    return includeExpressions.Aggregate(source, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));
}
```

This method assumes that you have a custom context object that inherits from `DbContext` and contains `DbSet<>` collections of your objects. It will find the appropriate one `DbSet<T>` and return a queryable collection that will pre-load specified sub-classes in your object. These are specified as an array of expressions. For example:

```
//example for object type 'Order'
var includes = new Expression<Func<Order, object>>[] {
    o => o.SalesItems.Select(p => p.Discounts), //load the 'SalesItems' collection AND the `Discounts` collection for each SalesItem
    o => o.Config.PriceList,                    //load the Config object AND the PriceList sub-object
    o => o.Tenders,                             //load the 'Tenders' collection
    o => o.Customer                             //load the 'Customer' object
};
```

To retrieve my queryable collection, I now call it as such:

```
var queryableOrders = context.GetQueryable(includes);
```

Again, the purpose here is to create a queryable object that will eagerly load only the sub-objects (and sub-sub-objects) that you actually want.

To get a specific item, use this like any other queryable source:

```
var order = context.GetQueryable(includes).FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderNumber == myOrderNumber);
```

Note that you can also provide the include expression inline; however, you will need to specify the generic:

```
//you can provide includes inline if you just have a couple
var order = context.GetQueryable<Order>(o => o.Tenders, o => o.SalesItems).FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderNumber == myOrderNumber);
```

Comment: What if recursion depth is unknown?

Comment: I also modified the question with something I tried. Do suggest if there is an easy way to solve `collection modified` error.

Comment: The recursion check isn't required as long as you don't have any circular references (i.e. `Person.Address.State.Person`). You can remove the recursion depth in that case, and you also won't get the collection modified error.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. It only return the parent and not the childs. As soon as you detach the parent entity, the child are no longer accessible.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh, I don't know your implementation, but I suspect it's not working because you haven't eagerly loaded all your data. I've updated my answer with the details of how I make sure all my data is in place before I use this method.